# Availability of T-SQL Code coverage Tool

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, code-coverage

I got a new assignment from my project head. We have `code coverage tools` for .NET and JAVA (?). But such tools are not available for SQL coverage which will display the flow of the stored procedures. Is there any such tool is available so that we will be able to go through all conditions, loops, cursors etc? I have put forwarded a suggestion for adding audit table to log the steps in the stored procedure. But this will not work as we have more than 1000 stored procedures in our environment.

I am modifying my post to inlcude the steps that I have took for adding the trace in SQL Profiler.

```
CREATE procedure dbo.sp_testtrace(@traceID int)
AS
BEGIN
      --Test Comments Added for the Trace
      DECLARE @pm_value as int
      IF @traceID <= 1
      BEGIN
            Select @pm_value = item_id from item where Item_id = @traceID
            Select 'The TRACE will reach here if the Parameter (@traceID) is Less than or Equal to 1'
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
            IF @traceID > 2
            BEGIN
                  Select @pm_value = item_id from RX, item where Item_id = @traceID
                  Select 'The TRACE will reach here if the Parameter (@traceID) is Greater to 2'
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                  Select @pm_value = rx_id from RX where RX_ID = @traceID
                  Select 'The TRACE will reach here if the Parameter (@traceID) is Equal to 2'
            END
      END
      Select 'Success'
END

GO
```

1) Added a new table for Trace. Example dbo.Trace_rpt

[image: Added a new table for Trace. Example dbo.Trace_rpt]

2) In the SQL Profiler, set the SP:StmtCompleted
[image]

3) In the SQL Profiler, set the RPC:Completed
[image]

4) Executed the Stored Procedure by passing the Parameter as 2

```
Exec sp_testtrace 2
```

5)  The results in the table can be extracted based on the Database ID and Object ID. **Here it is 7 and 735146210**

```
(Select Object_id (N'sp_testtrace'))
Select * from trace_rpt where databaseID= 7 and ObjectID = 735146210
```

The results is given below

> -- sp_testtrace  IF @traceID <= 1
>   -- sp_testtrace  IF @traceID > 2
>   -- sp_testtrace  Select @pm_value = rx_id from RX where RX_ID = @traceID
>   -- sp_testtrace  Select 'The TRACE will reach here if the Parameter (@traceID) is Equal to 2'
>   -- sp_testtrace  Select 'Success'

But it does not give me the information about the parameters that I have passed (**Here it is 2**).
Please help me by suggesting your valuable opinions.

Comment: Someone posted his coverage tool for sql in github https://github.com/jbarker7/sqlcc

Comment: I have checked this. But it is not fit in our current environment. I am trying to use the SQL Profiler SP:StmtCompleted for creating the code coverage tool. But I am not able to extract the parameter and variable values through the profiler. I have tried the RPC:Completed, but this is also not showing the Parameter / Variable values in the Stored Procedure. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: You can save the results from the profiler in a table (File->Save As->Trace Table) and then you can work with the fields in that table like objectname and textdata .. so once you know the procedure name you can get the definition of the procedure and find all its parameters.

Comment: Okay i could not edit my comment so im writing a new one .. you can see the parameters and their values in the textdata field from the method i pointed out above.

Comment: find me in skype deepshadowdungeon